# Media queries for iPad vs iPad Air

Tags: css, ipad, air, media-queries

There are 2 Good discussions about `@media` queries on StackOverflow already. One of them is here: [CSS media queries work for iPad2, iPad Air, Samsung Galaxy, large screens but not the usual desktop screens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24815082/css-media-queries-work-for-ipad2-ipad-air-samsung-galaxy-large-screens-but-no).

Those discussions took place before the advent of the iPad Air. The iPad Air has a viewport of 2048 x 1536. I cannot find the webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio for it. I want to target the Air specifically because my AJAX site shrinks to half the size on it. This site is meant for landscape only.

So...

```
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
(-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.0)
```

-> targets the old iPad 2's

```
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
(-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2.0)
```

-> targets the iPad 3 & 4 retinas but it does not target the Air

I have tried variations of

```
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 1536px) 
and (max-device-width : 2048px) 
and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2.0)
```

to try and get the Air to react. Who out there has had experience developing for the new Airs?

Comment: It's Safari that is rendering half-size on the Air. Not Chrome. How do you do a browser detection?

Answer (score 4):

you need viewport sizes http://viewportsizes.com/?filter=ipad
Air has viewport 1024x768 too

Answer (score 1):

I had problems with developing for the new ipad air 3. i barely found exakt information about viewport size for media-query. A friend told me that it has same size like ipad pro (10.5 inch) so i went to following apple developer site:
https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/DeviceInformation/Reference/iOSDeviceCompatibility/Displays/Displays.html

There it was important to take the UIKit Size from Table 2-1. After all my query for targetting exactly the ipad air 3 (in landscape mode) looked like this: `@media all and (device-width: 834px) and (device-height: 1112px) and (orientation:landscape) {}`

Answer (score 1):

You can try this, I tried it and it worked.

iPad Air 5th Gen:

```
@media only screen and (width: 820px) and (height: 1106px) {}
@media only screen and (width: 1180px) and (height: 746px) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

To target specific styles for iPad and iPad Air using media queries, you can utilize the screen size and resolution differences between the two devices. Here are some media queries that you can use:
**iPad**

```
/* Portrait */
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) 
and (orientation: portrait) {
  /* CSS styles specific to iPad portrait mode */
}

/* Landscape */
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) 
and (orientation: landscape) {
 /* CSS styles specific to iPad landscape mode */
}
```

**iPad Air**

```
/* Portrait */
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) 
and (orientation: portrait) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
 /* CSS styles specific to iPad Air portrait mode */
}
/* Landscape */
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) 
and (orientation: landscape) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
 /* CSS styles specific to iPad Air landscape mode */
}
```

**Hope this help you**